# Adding quick walkthrough about the APP in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and I have created an Todo app, for that I want to add a quick guide once the the users opens the app for the first time after installation.

I have seen something like that in the ICICI mobile app, there once you installed it will give a you a quick tour about what all option you will get with a pointing arrow, below that its description and a next button, I want to do similar to that in my flutter application.

Can anyone who had implemented the same, or know about it , can you share the same.

Thanks

Comment: The image is missing bro.

Comment: Try this my sample app https://github.com/manojalwisnz/flutter_walkthrough

Answer (score 1):

Here is the plugin named- [feature_discovery](https://pub.dev/packages/feature_discovery) which shows the app tour guide following the material design guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple what all you need ::

1. Whole screen image including pointing arrow.
2. Your Button to go next and previous.
3. Connect all screens using navigation.

That's it,

Thanks.